# Open Google Voice app with specific number

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to implement call feature without sharing my actual SIM number. So I am trying to use Google Voice for that. Is it possible to open Google Voice app and automatically select a specific number. I will perform the call action manually.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can use `canopenUrl` concept

Comment: But how to pass phone number that I want to select by default? Is there any URL schema that Google Voice accepts. I tried to search but only found one that just opens the app.